# Is there any trivial case when `OnclickListener doesn't` work on a activity?

Tags: java, android, view, onclick

I implemented the interface `View.OnclickListener` and `Override` the method `onClick`.
Problem is, all other buttons and view response on click, but a particular button doesn't work.

Java code for that button is:

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.btnResetPass){
        Log.i("test", "In ResetButton");
        resetPassword();
    }
```

and `xml` file code for this button is:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnResetPass"
    android:text="Reset"/>
```

Nothing happens when I click on this button. But all other `Views` and `Buttons` in this `onClick` method
work properly accept this one. Why isn't it working then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the Listener

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Shame on me! 
I often do this mistake, still i couldn't find it. :( :(

Comment: Thank you!
God, this is negative trivial :(

Comment: Glad I could Help .